# Upload with FTP a form file in PHP

Tags: php, forms, ftp

I have this form:

```
<form action="after.php" method="post" id="divulgacao">
    <div style="float: left;width: 195px; margin-right: 10px;">
        <p class="pdados">Your name</p>
        <input class="campodivulgue" name="titulo" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;width: 195px; margin-right: 10px;">
        <p class="pdados">E-mail</p>
        <input class="campodivulgue" name="email" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 195px; ">
        <p class="pdados">Your picture</p>
        <input style="float:left; height: 22px;"  type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    </div>                  
    <p align="right" style="margin-top: 10px;"><input class="btn" type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Send" /></p>                       
</form>
```

What should I do so when the user clicks on the send button, the chosen file in the file field is uploaded using FTP? What should be the content of the file after.php

Do I have to put another form for file upload?

Comment: afaik you can't do it with ftp unless you are sending a local file (that is where you php code is to some other ftp that you are aware of the user and password or accepts anonymous ftp)... what you want is http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the enctype attribute in the form.

```
<form action="after.php" method="post" id="divulgacao" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

example contents for after.php taken right from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

Comment: there doesn't have to be an FTP part unless you specifically need there to be for some reason?